# Run git commands without default gitconfig

Tags: git

Is there a way to run `git` commands without using the default gitconfig?

For example, say I had setup a custom diff tool in my gitconfig. If I wanted to use the default `git diff` (which uses `diff`?), how would I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--ext-diff` option with `git diff`. `--ext-diff` allows you to specify a different external diff tool.

Answer (score 4):

To ignore the system Git config (/etc/gitconfig), set the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` to `1` (or `true` or `yes`).
To ignore the global Git config (~/.gitconfig), set the environment variable  `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL` to `1` (or `true` or `yes`).

Example: `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL=1 git diff`

These options are available since ab88c36 (allow suppressing of global and system config, 2008-02-06). The first release (candidate) that appears to know them is 1.5.5-rc0 (`git describe --contains ab88c36`).

Comment: This was [removed in 2011](http://git.kaarsemaker.net/git/commit/8f323c00dd3c9b396b01a1aeea74f7dfd061bb7f/) but `HOME= git diff` will prevent Git from reading `$HOME/.gitconfig`, accomplishing the same thing (tested in Git v2.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL=1 HOME= XDG_CONFIG_HOME= git diff` to ensure that no outside configuration at all is read by git.

From the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITCONFIGNOSYSTEMcode):

> ## [`GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITCONFIGNOSYSTEMcode)
>
> Whether to skip reading settings from the system-wide `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig` file. **This environment variable can be used along with `$HOME` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to create a predictable environment** for a picky script, or you can set it temporarily to avoid using a buggy `/etc/gitconfig` file while waiting for someone with sufficient permissions to fix it.